# Is it possible to create a maps application with Matlab?

Tags: c#, matlab, google-maps, maps

I have an [ADS-B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_dependent_surveillance_%E2%80%93_broadcast) receiver with which I would like to create a Matlab application such as http://www.flightradar24.com (a little more basic, for sure), for tracking flights on a map.

In order to do so, I would need to if it is possible to implement an "interactive" map (Google Maps or similar). I know about the GUI tool in Matlab, but I'm not very familiar with it and I do not know its limitations. I would like to know if it is feasible to code this application with Matlab (regarding Maps), since I'm already used to working with ADS-B signal and data.

If Matlab is not a proper language for this purpose, could you please indicate me some other language that allows me to do this? I have been thinking about C#, since it has a lot of visual applications, however, no idea if it is possible to implement an interactive map either.

P.S.: I have never worked with maps in any coding language, I will have to start from zero.

Comment: Take a look at the mapping toolbox!

Comment: or look at "plot_google_map" on the mathworks file exchange. I already use this function, work like a charm. After that if you can get the coordinate of each flight from your ADS-B it won't be too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

[Mapping Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping/) provides algorithms, functions, and an app for analyzing geographic data and creating map displays in MATLAB®. You can import vector and raster data from a wide range of file formats and web map servers. The toolbox lets you subset and customize data using trimming, interpolation, resampling, coordinate transformations, and other techniques. Geospatial data can be combined with base map layers from multiple sources in a single map display. By incorporating mapping functions into MATLAB programs, you can automate frequent tasks in your geospatial workflow.

If you want to use C#, then I think this [tutorials](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32643/GMap-NET-Great-Maps-for-Windows-Forms-and-Presenta) can help you.

But if you want more detail tutorials plus example, then I recommended you to check this [Google Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).